# Sending cron output to email?

Tags: email, cron

I'm trying to send cron output to an email address and am struggling... I'm running the following command:

```
13 15 * * 1-5 root /path/to/mysql-backup.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Daily Database Backup Report" my.email@emailhost.com
```

That shows this error within `/var/mail/root`

```
/usr/bin/mail: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/mail: line 1: `Config file not found (-s)'
```

Is this trying to validate/execute the output of the cron?

Do you do this on your server?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, `/usr/bin/mail` is a binary executable, but on your system the shell seems to be loading and interpreting it. `syntax error near unexpected token` is a **bash** diagnostic.

This can happen if you have overwritten an executable. Is there any conceivable chance that you have overwritten `/usr/bin/mail` with the text "Config file not found (-s)", causing said text to be fed to the shell when you try to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **mailx** if it works? or check if you can do the mail within the bash script itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the outcome of your script ´/path/to/mysql-backup.sh´ is binary, and the reason why mail runs into the error is because you cannot simply pipe binary output without encoding it.

A good way to attach files on command line is `mutt`. Check out the discussion at [how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line).